# Route shall change after route transition/animation has been triggered

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have an animation that is being fired on route change. It's a black `div` being translated from the bottom to the top covering the whole page during the transition.

The animation for the `div` works fine, but currently, the route is being changed simultaneous to the `div`'s animation start - kind of destroying the whole transition. **I want the route to be changed, just when the `div` is covering the whole page to have a seamless route transition.**

Do I need a different approach?

[image]

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet #myOutlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
<div class="transition-overlay" [@translate]="getDepth(myOutlet)"></div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('translate', [
      state('1', style({transform: 'translateY(100vh)'})),
      state('2', style({transform: 'translateY(-100vh)'})),
      transition('1=>2', [ animate('1500ms ease-in-out')]),
      transition('2=>1', [ animate('1500ms ease-in-out')])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  ...

  getDepth(outlet) {
    return outlet.activatedRouteData['depth'];
  }

}
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: { depth: 1 }},
  {path: 'cases', component: WorkComponent, data: { depth: 2 }},
];
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Router Resolver` to wait until the animation is done and then move the the route from one to another.

[angular document](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

here is sample code

```
{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  data: { depth: 1 },
  resolve: { items: SomeResolver }
}
```

And the resolver

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from './api.service';

import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';

import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class SomeResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private apiService: APIService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return **your condition**;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to wait for the animation to be halfway through, since it shall already be changed, when the black overlay is transitioning out again. Is this behavior possible with a resolver as well?

Comment: And I want the content from the first page to not disappear until it's fully covered by the overlay, I don't think that's possible using a resolver.

Comment: Router resolver will not load the component until the first component finished loaded